# Corrupted image is produced using base64 encryption

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to upload an image and the postman request is in base64 encoding, however a corrupted image is produced. The code for the upload is:

```
  byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(image);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            AddBlobRequest blobRequest = new AddBlobRequest()
            {
                ContainerName = ContainerName,
                SourceFileStream = stream,
                BlobName = fileName
            };
            BlobStorageManager.Instance.AddBlob(blobRequest);
```

Comment: Why not `Encoding.ASCII`? That could be the problem.

Comment: `Base64` is not encryption, its encoding. https://danielmiessler.com/study/encoding-encryption-hashing-obfuscation/#gs.CnAPcE8

Comment: `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` does not convert an image to base64 encoding.  It converts a string to UTF8 encoding.  You need to use `Convert.ToBase64String()`.  I'm going to mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: change the UFT8 encoding to byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(image);